# iOS DateComponentsFormatter - get used units

Tags: ios, localization, nstimeinterval, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I would like to formate time from seconds to positional format like **2:05 min** or **1:23 h** or **19 s**. I'm having problem of retrieving localised abbreviated unit of time. Here is my code.

```
let secs: Double = 3801
let stopWatchFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
stopWatchFormatter.unitsStyle = .positional
stopWatchFormatter.maximumUnitCount = 2
stopWatchFormatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
print(stopWatchFormatter.string(from: secs)) // 1:03
stopWatchFormatter.unitsStyle = .short
print(stopWatchFormatter.string(from: secs)) // 1 hr, 3 min
```

As you can see 3801 seconds is formatted to 1:03, which is fine but I don't know whether `DateComponentsFormatter` used hours or minutes etc.
I may use simple MOD logic to check it, but then comes hard part of localisation. Also notice that MOD solution is worthless if I set `collapsesLargestUnit` to `false`.

Comment: If you select `.positional` and use `maximumUnitCount`, you're just not going to know. You will either need to use `.short` (1 hr, 3 min) or `.abbreviated` (1h 3m). If you want "1:03 min" (I wouldn't recommend that as that's not at all clear to me what that means), you'll have to get the `DateComponents` and build a localized string yourself (with your own localized version of whatever abbreviations you want). But `DateComponentsFormatter` cannot do that particular custom format for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateComponentsFormatter` doesn't directly support the format you want which is essentially the positional format but with the first unit of the short format shown at the end.

The following helper function combines those two separate results into what you want. This should work with any locale but thorough testing needs to be done to confirm that.

```
func formatStopWatchTime(seconds: Double) -> String {
    let stopWatchFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    stopWatchFormatter.unitsStyle = .positional
    stopWatchFormatter.maximumUnitCount = 2
    stopWatchFormatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    var pos = stopWatchFormatter.string(from: seconds)!

    // Work around a bug where some values return 3 units despite only requesting 2 units
    let parts = pos.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
    if parts.count > 2 {
        let seps = pos.components(separatedBy: .decimalDigits).filter { !$0.isEmpty }
        pos = parts[0..<2].joined(separator: seps[0])
    }

    stopWatchFormatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
    stopWatchFormatter.unitsStyle = .short
    let unit = stopWatchFormatter.string(from: seconds)!

    // Replace the digits in the unit result with the pos result
    let res = unit.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\\d]+", with: pos, options: [.regularExpression])

    return res
}

print(formatStopWatchTime(seconds: 3801))
```

Output:

> 1:03 hr

Comment: I noticed it doesn't work for 3601 seconds. I would expect output 1:00 hr but I got 1:00:01 hr. In other words, it doesn't show 2 unit counts but 3.

Comment: Odd. There is a bug in `DateComponentsFormatter` where any value of `seconds` that represents any number of hours and minutes with 0-59 seconds or any number of hours and exactly 1 minute, results in 3 units being returned in the string instead of the requested 2. Example - any `seconds` in the range 3600 - 3660 or 7200-7260, etc. I've updated the answer with a hack that deals with this.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand you need no String, but DateComponent:

```
let dateA = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
let dateB = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: dateA, to: dateB)
```

Comment: No. I need localised string in format `xx:yy unit`, where xx is biggest non-null value and yy is following, unit is localised string of unit used for xx. It is for stop watch purpose. In other words I need something like [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/lengthformatter/1407661-unitstring) but for time and not length.

Comment: `DateComponentsFormatter` lacking custom style. Having `DateComponents` you can print them in whatever format you want.